# Where has the instant rename refactor prompt gone in VS2015?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, resharper, automated-refactoring

In <= VS2013, whenever I rename a type or member, I see a short little red line under the end of the new name, and a prompt to use Ctrl+Alt+F10 to rename refactor.

Since my recent switch to 2015 Community, with ReSharper 9, this convenience seems to have vanished, or been hidden. Now when I rename something, the new name is surrounded by a dashed-line border, and only when I hover my mouse pointer over the new name, then I see a context menu which offers the rename refactor command, but with no keyboard shortcut suggested.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to check Resharper options. Options->Code Inspection->Settings->Visual Studio Integration->Do not show Visual Studio bulb.

Switching this option off might solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you're using Resharper, almost all quick-actions are under <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd>, after changing the name inline. With Resharper installed, the quick access key for rename is (by default) under <kbd>F2</kbd>. And the refactor menu can be found under <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>.

The default Visual studio command to open the [...] menu is <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>, this allows you to apply the rename refactor after changing the name inline. Rename is the same default as under Resharper <kbd>F2</kbd> or <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>,<kbd>r</kbd>.

Comment: My alt+enter stopped working ages ago for some reason, but the VS ctrl+. is nice, but not as nice as Shit+Alt+F10. Thanks.

Comment: Fix your alt-enter by resetting your visualstudio and Resharper keyboard bindings.